# Dropzone.js does not support older browsers! (chrome version is 77+ & updated)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, jquery-file-upload

My problem is that the same code of template in template is working and not showing this alert but when i use this in my project (i am using laravel 5.5), it is showing this alert

> Dropzone.js does not support older browsers!

whenever i refresh the browser. Even the browser is same (chrome version 77+ & updated). As this alert is not showing in template the it should not appear in my project as well. Please help me out!

**Here is relevant HTML code**

```
<div>
  <form action="./dummy.html" class="dropzone well" id="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple="" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="preview-template" class="hide">
   <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
       <div class="dz-image">
         <img data-dz-thumbnail="" />
       </div>

       <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size">
           <span data-dz-size=""></span>
         </div>

         <div class="dz-filename">
           <span data-dz-name=""></span>
         </div>
       </div>

     <div class="dz-progress">
       <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span>
     </div>

     <div class="dz-error-message">
       <span data-dz-errormessage=""></span>
     </div>

     <div class="dz-success-mark">
       <span class="fa-stack fa-lg bigger-150">
         <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x white"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x fa-inverse green"></i>
       </span>
     </div>

     <div class="dz-error-mark">
       <span class="fa-stack fa-lg bigger-150">
         <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x white"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x fa-inverse red"></i>
       </span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Here is relevant jQuery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
  try {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {
      previewTemplate: $('#preview-template').html(),

    thumbnailHeight: 120,
      thumbnailWidth: 120,
      maxFilesize: 50.5,

    //addRemoveLinks : true,
    //dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',

    dictDefaultMessage :
    '<span class="bigger-150 bolder"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right red"></i> Drop files</span> to upload \
    <span class="smaller-80 grey">(or click)</span> <br /> \
    <i class="upload-icon ace-icon fa fa-cloud-upload blue fa-3x"></i>'
  ,

      thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
        if (file.previewElement) {
          $(file.previewElement).removeClass("dz-file-preview");
          var images = $(file.previewElement).find("[data-dz-thumbnail]").each(function() {
        var thumbnailElement = this;
        thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
        thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;
      });
          setTimeout(function() { $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-image-preview"); }, 1);
        }
      }

    });


    //simulating upload progress
    var minSteps = 6,
        maxSteps = 60,
        timeBetweenSteps = 100,
        bytesPerStep = 100000;

    myDropzone.uploadFiles = function(files) {
      var self = this;

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
            totalSteps = Math.round(Math.min(maxSteps, Math.max(minSteps, file.size / bytesPerStep)));

        for (var step = 0; step < totalSteps; step++) {
          var duration = timeBetweenSteps * (step + 1);
          setTimeout(function(file, totalSteps, step) {
            return function() {
              file.upload = {
                progress: 100 * (step + 1) / totalSteps,
                total: file.size,
                bytesSent: (step + 1) * file.size / totalSteps
              };

              self.emit('uploadprogress', file, file.upload.progress, file.upload.bytesSent);
              if (file.upload.progress == 100) {
                file.status = Dropzone.SUCCESS;
                self.emit("success", file, 'success', null);
                self.emit("complete", file);
                self.processQueue();
              }
            };
          }(file, totalSteps, step), duration);
        }
      }
     }


     //remove dropzone instance when leaving this page in ajax mode
     $(document).one('ajaxloadstart.page', function(e) {
      try {
        myDropzone.destroy();
      } catch(e) {}
     });

  } catch(e) {
    alert('Dropzone.js does not support older browsers!');
  }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Chrome 7 is so old though, latest is 75+

Comment: Also, don't use useless bold while posting a question

Comment: sorry its 77+ and updated. i will edit. btw do you know how i can solve this???

Comment: Are you aware that `e` in `catch(e)` contains usable information?

Comment: @MatJ I can't get enough from your question but as far as i know "e" contains error's/exception's information. If you are referring to something else then please let me know about that so that i can get benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have solved the problem. The reason for the problem was very basic that i was using the **Dropzone.js** file in the header (My team mate move the js files in header). After placing the js file  in footer, problem has been gone.